# How do I calculate typical group size?

Tags: statistics

If I have a set of groups of individuals (e.g. people), and I want to calculate the typical group size (as observed by individuals), how do I do this?

Wikipedia refers to this as "mean crowding" or "Typical Group Size" but doesn't give a formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_size_measures

I believe the "typical group size" for a set of group sizes $\{a_1, a_2,..., a_n\}$ is simply:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2 }$$

i.e. the root mean square or quadratic mean.

Is that correct? Is there a better way to characterise typical group size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precise definition (according to the Wikipedia link in your question) seems to be that the *typical* group size is the average size of the group *as observed by the individuals of your population*. Thus, if you have a population of $N$ individuals, split into $K$ groups with size $n_k$ (thus, $\sum_{k=1}^K n_k = N$), the typical group size would be $$
  T = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^K \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_K} n_k\right) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^K n_k^2
$$
since the $n_k$ individuals in group $k$ all observe a group size of $n_k$.

It's entirely possible that it's for some reason more convenient to define the typical group size as $\sqrt{T}$ instead of plain $T$, but it then ceases to be the average group size as observed by the individuals.

Comment: Thanks! My answer actually wasn't $\sqrt{T}$ because it had 1/K, not 1/N.

Comment: @spookylukey Hm, true. Then I don't see an obvious connection between the two formulas. Where did your formula come from?

Comment: my own head! more of a guess really, on the basis that I knew it must be related to the square of the items, but I didn't think it through.